# Using Multithreading with RMI

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, rmi

How can I gain access to the thread pool used in RMI?

I read that RMI manages thread creation for each remote call but I want a way in which I can manipulate the thread creation.

I need to limit the number of threads so that, for example, only two threads serve two clients, and if another client makes a call, it will wait for one of the two previously created threads to become available.

In other words, I want to implement a fixed-size thread pool in RMI. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I get access to thread pool used in RMI?

There is no thread pool used in RMI. At least not in the Sun/Oracle-built RMI.

> I read that RMI manage the process of threads creation for each remote call

Certainly but not via a thread pool.

> but I want a way in which I can manipulate in that process. I need to limit the number of threads so that only two thread -for example- are serve two clients, and if another client make a call, it will wait for one of this threads be available.

You don't state why, and it sounds like a terrible idea, or else a job for a counting semaphore, but you can't do this as described. The RMI Specification carefully makes no guarantees about the association of threads to clients.

> In other words i want to implement a thread pool with fixed size in RMI.
>   How can I do that?

You can't.

Comment: can you provide possible directions on how such a functionality can achieved? I've seen many similar question with similar shut-down answers.

Comment: @slmatrix With a counting semaphore, as I had already written here three and a half years before you asked.